# Is there a way to check that a macro is defined as a specific thing?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

As far as I know, `#ifdef` can only check if a macro is defined, not what a macro is defined as.

```
#define MY_NUMBER 1
.
.
.
#ifdef MY_NUMBER
function();
#endif
```

I've tried something like this:

```
#define MY_NUMBER 1
.
.
.
#ifdef MY_NUMBER 1
function();
#endif
```

and the compiler issues the following:

```
warning: extra tokens at end of #ifdef directive
```

and the value of the macro is not taken into account (it's just ignored).

**How do I check if a macro has a specific value?**

Comment: `#ifdef MY_NUMBER 1` --> `#if MY_NUMBER == 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like in conditional statements, you can use equality (`==`) or inequality (`<` / `>` / `<=` / `>=`) in your preprocessor directives:

```
#if MY_NUMBER == 1
  function1();
#elif MY_NUMBER == 2
  function2();
#else
  function3();
#endif
```

Comment: Okay, that worked for numbers, but how do I check for non-numbers? (for example, #ifdef PLATFORM WINDOWS)

Comment: @user_194421, your original comment said "for strings", and, unfortunately, C does not have a native support for strings, and cannot really compare them with preprocessor. Usually, to check platforms, you'd just use `ifdef`.

Comment: But `WINDOWS` isn't a string... it's a token (more importantly, it's a [token that can be pasted into an identifier](https://godbolt.org/g/tQeRL1)).  (Not that platform tests in practice use this technique.)